# XSL function affects performance

Tags: xml, performance, function, xslt

Consider that codes below loops in more than 1000 Layer Entities. Which one will be faster in terms of performance? Does the use of function affects/add time to the execution time? I want to use the function for redundancy but afraid it will affect the performance.

**XSL that use function**

```
        <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xpath-default-namespace="http://ratabase.cgi.com/" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:test="http://www.test.com" exclude-result-prefixes="xs xsl test">
      <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:function name="test:getPolicyOuputValue">
      <xsl:param name="curGroup" />
      <xsl:param name="premiumField" />
      <xsl:param name="peril" />
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum($curGroup/Regions/Region[Inputs/Field/Name='INTERNAL_PERIL' and Inputs/Field/upper-case(Value)='WIND']/Outputs/Field[Name= 'LAYERPERIL_ANNUAL_TECHNICAL_PREM_AMT']/Value[text()]),'#')"/>
      </xsl:function>   


      <xsl:template name="buildLayerEntity">
        <xsl:variable name="Layer" select="Inputs/Field[Name='INTERNAL_LAYER_NO']/Value"/>
        <Layer ID="{Inputs/Field[Name='INTERNAL_LAYER_ID']/Value}" ExtAction="U">

          <Layer_Wind_Annual_Technical_Prem_Amt>
            <xsl:value-of select="test:getPolicyOuputValue(., 'LAYERPERIL_ANNUAL_TECHNICAL_PREM_AMT', 'WIND')"/>
          </Layer_Wind_Annual_Technical_Prem_Amt>
          <Layer_Wind_ITD_Technical_Prem_Amt>
            <xsl:value-of select="test:getPolicyOuputValue(., 'LAYERPERIL_ANNUAL_TECHNICAL_PREM_AMT', 'WIND')"/>
          </Layer_Wind_ITD_Technical_Prem_Amt>
          .... 30 other fields using the function passing same value in curGroup parameter

        </Layer>
      </xsl:template>
```

**XSL that use hardcode**

```
      <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xpath-default-namespace="http://ratabase.cgi.com/" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:test="http://www.test.com" exclude-result-prefixes="xs xsl test">
      <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>


      <xsl:template name="buildLayerEntity">
        <xsl:variable name="Layer" select="Inputs/Field[Name='INTERNAL_LAYER_NO']/Value"/>
        <Layer ID="{Inputs/Field[Name='INTERNAL_LAYER_ID']/Value}" ExtAction="U">

          <Layer_Wind_Annual_Technical_Prem_Amt>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(Regions/Region[Inputs/Field/Name='INTERNAL_PERIL' and Inputs/Field/upper-case(Value)='WIND']/Outputs/Field[Name= 'LAYERPERIL_ANNUAL_TECHNICAL_PREM_AMT']/Value[text()]),'#')"/>
          </Layer_Wind_Annual_Technical_Prem_Amt>     

          <Layer_Wind_ITD_Technical_Prem_Amt>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(Regions/Region[Inputs/Field/Name='INTERNAL_PERIL' and Inputs/Field/upper-case(Value)='WIND']/Outputs/Field[Name= 'LAYERPERIL_ITD_TECHNICAL_PREM_AMT']/Value[text()]),'#')"/>
          </Layer_Wind_ITD_Technical_Prem_Amt>    
          .... 30 other fields

        </Layer>
      </xsl:template>
```

Comment: What do your measurements show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't tell you whether one stylesheet performs faster than another without knowing what XSLT processor you are using (and, in principle, exact details of how you are running it). It also depends on your requirements, for example do you want to minimize compile time or execution time? (that depends on whether you are using the same stylesheet repeatedly). If you are using Saxon-EE, the optimizer will inline small functions like this, so there is no call overhead, but if you are using Saxon-HE then it won't.

And are you really prepared to sacrifice stylesheet readability and maintainability for a couple of microseconds in improved performance? That isn't a good trade-off except in the most extreme circumstances.

Measure it and see. But define your requirement first.

And if you want to improve your stylesheet in a way that will benefit readability and maintainability and performance as well, here are some suggestions:

- Declare the types of your function arguments, and the function return type, using an `as` attribute
- Use `xsl:sequence` rather than `xsl:value-of` to return the function result. The xsl:value-of instruction creates a text node, which is quite unnecessary overhead when you only want to return a string.
- If the number of fields is large (and especially if you aren't using a processor like Saxon-EE with advanced optimization) consider using keys or maps for faster lookup of fields by name.